# Calling a suspend function from inside Runnable.run()

Tags: kotlin, parallel-processing, kotlin-coroutines, runnable

I think conceptually this should work. But there is an error:

> Suspend function 'dueWorkingHours' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

Is Java and Kotlin parallelization not compatible? Is there a way around this?

Actually, I have the `Runnable` only to through it into a `Handler`:

```
handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 100)
```

If there is a similar concept in Kotlin that I could use instead that would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not just a matter of Java and Kotlin parallelism being compatible or not. Even in pure Kotlin projects, you can never call suspend functions from outside a coroutine or other suspend function. There has to be some coroutine entry point for the suspend function to have a CoroutineContext, CoroutineScope, and Continuation, which are necessary ingredients for coroutines to work.

If you want to start a coroutine that does something after a delay, you use a CoroutineScope to launch a coroutine and you can call `delay()` as the first thing you do in that coroutine.

Comment: My project is actually pure Kotlin, nevertheless I think of a Runnable as a Java construct.

Comment: Actually, it's a repeating task. The Runnable inserts itself in the Handler again. I guess I could do that with a method as well, simply calling it recusively. Or is there a more elegant construct in Kotlin I could make use of?

Comment: I just went for a `while (true)` loop. No recursion necessary.

Comment: Yes, a while(true) loop in a coroutine is the most sensible way to do that pattern. By pure Kotlin, I meant even if you were using Kotlin-defined interfaces, there would be no way to call suspend functions in them unless the abstract function of the interface was also defined as `suspend`. A coroutine cannot exist without a CoroutineScope and CorotuineContext.